# Convert CrmDateTime to System.DateTime

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm

Easy question of the day...

What do I need to do to convert a CrmDateTime to a .NET System.DateTime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateTime.Parse(crmdatetime.Value)
```